# Is it possible to put Cisco Aironet 1000 APs in standalone mode?

Tags: cisco, access-point

Almost all of the documentation that I've read seems to suggest that a controller is required,  but I've been assigned to sell my employer's old 1000's and finally get rid of the ancient 4400 series controller. Can I reset/unjoin the Aironet APs from the controller and have them run in standalone mode? Does a standalone mode even exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  [That entire product line is "lightweight" only](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6306/index.html), so no autonomous/standalone operation mode is possible on that hardware.

The product line's end end of sale as well, so I don't know how much your employer expects to get for them, but they're going to be disappointed.  Seriously, a quick search on eBay shows them being offered for as little as $19.95 and as much as $50, so it's probably not even worth the time to try and sell them.